Control stdin and the way it is displayed on terminal
A while  back I wrote a simple terminal typing game using termios.h. The game consists of a status line, a prompt line, and an input line. It looks as follows
Time: 18 CPM: 49.00 WPM: 9.00

>Reddit is a website that bills itself as the "front page of the<
 Reddit is a website that bills itslef as the "front
 Quit key pressed. Exiting...

Press ESC to finish game

Where correct characters are typed they are displayed blue and wrong ones in red. termios.h helps me collect a character at a time from the user without displaying it first. This helps me check if the character has to be red or blue, this is also How i keep score.
I am trying to rewrite this program without termios.h with the purpose of understanding stdin and stdout more. The problem I have is that I am unable to collect and examine user input.
A minimal reproducible example of my problem is as follows

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COL_LIMIT 80 // Make sure you don't type more than 80 chars.

int main() {
    char inputBuffer[COL_LIMIT]; // I want to store input here

    // Fill the buffer with default values
    memset(inputBuffer, '_', COL_LIMIT);

    // Set the stream to fully buffered, I thought this would solve my problem...
    if (
    setvbuf(
        stdin,       // I want to control stdin
        inputBuffer, // I want the input to go to this buffer...
        _IOFBF,      // I want the stream to write into the buffer, not the terminal
        COL_LIMIT    // .. I dont need to store a ton of input.
        ) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting buffer for stdin\n");
        return 1;
    }

    time_t current_time = 0, end_time = 0;
    time(&current_time);
    end_time = current_time + 5; // run for 5 seconds

    printf("Collectin input");
    while(current_time <= end_time){
      time(&current_time);
      printf(
         "\033[?25l" // hide the cursor
         "No stdin should be displayed in the terminal...\n"
             "\033[1A\r\033[K" // go to the previous line
         );
    }

    fflush(stdin);  // flush any straglers

    // Print the contents of the buffer
    printf(
       "\033[?25l" // show the cursor again
       "\n[STDIN %s]\n", inputBuffer); // this should print whatever was typed.

    return 0;
}


The current output of the program shows something like this
No stdin should be displayed in the terminal...the terminal...
[STDIN ________________________________________________________________________________]

This is after typing less than 80 chars while the loop is running. I expected my input
to be displayed instead of the continuous "_"
Is my goal even possible?

What you're trying to do is just not supported by the C stdio functions. You need to go to a lower, direct-to-terminal level, either through termios or using a library like ncurses. With that said, you could use terminal escape sequences for output, and achieve similar results if the terminal support it. But for input there's no replacement.

@Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the input. Am not interested in going the scape sequences route (it would probable be possible if I changed the input of the text to blend in with the background). My intent is to specifically manipulate the stream.

You will need termios on Linux to place the stdin in raw (noncannonical) mode rather than cooked mode. This is what allows you to intercept each key on the keypress without waiting for the user to press return. You can use preprocessor conditionals to selectively include code for Linux, or Windows, etc. that does a different setup based on OS. You may like Build Your Own Text Editor which is an excellent tutorial in low-level console I/O.

See also Canonical vs non-canonical terminal input.

For linux see man tcsetattr and here flags ICANON, ECHO and TCSANOW.

Your move with setvbuf ain’t gonna fly for real-time character input 'cause, in the terminal, stdin's all line-buffered. That means input ain't even hitting the program till you hit Enter. If you're trying to grab characters one by one, you can roll with getc() or getchar() to snatch a single character at a time. But heads up, it’s still gonna show up on the screen.
Now, if you wanna keep it low-key like your termios.h game, where the input stays hidden, you're gonna need some system-specific tricks (like termios.h or conio.h if you're messin' with Windows). Standard C ain't got no built-in way to do that character-by-character, ninja-style, without putting it on blast. So yeah, setvbuf ain't cutting it for this one.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Answer] (and [Ask]) pages.  Discourse on SO is expected to use reasonably formal English.  I debated about replacing "ain't" and "gonna" and "wanna", but left them.  And "messin'" is similarly colloquial — the apostrophe is "correct but surprising (to me)".

I swear, the way this was written originally sounded more like an LLM-generated answer deliberately written in an extremely “casual” style. I’m not even sure it is accurate given that the default input mode only flushes complete lines to the terminal (i.e. getc and friends won’t even see anything until a new line).

Anyway, the answerer should be aware that AI-generated answers are not welcome on the platform, if that’s indeed what was used to write the answer.
